# How can I write a script or a batch that will enable me to change image file name to each specific name?

Tags: vba, batch-file, cmd

I have a bunch of images (thousands) that their file name correspond to an employee number in a spreadsheet. How do I write a script that will change the file name of the image into an an employee number?

**This is how spreadsheet looks like:**

I have two columns in a spreadsheet "Employeenumber" e.g: 10003568 & "FileName" e.g: A647AC16825A4DBF86E0b704E4E9F853(1).jpg and thousands of rows.

I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Every time I have to do this, I add another column and in it I compose CMD commands to operate on the data in that row.

So, say you were working in row 2, column C. This formula (in Excel) would be similar to what I'd do.

```
=CONCATENATE("rename """,a2,""" """,b2,".jpg""")
```

The resulting text would look like

```
rename "A647AC16825A4DBF86E0b704E4E9F853(1).jpg" "10003568.jpg"
```

It would probably be best to include the path to the source image (or both images if you wanted to copy the images to a new location.

Then, copy all the column C cells and paste them into a .CMD script and run it.

Comment: It is possible to do this with VBA, but in my experience, it's a lot more work.